# Bash script to set up a temporary SSH tunnel

Tags: bash, ssh

On Cygwin, I want a Bash script to:

1. Create an SSH tunnel to a remote server.
2. Do some work locally that uses the tunnel.
3. Then shut down the tunnel.

The shutdown part has me perplexed.

Currently, I have a lame solution. In one shell I run the following to create a tunnel:

```
# Create the tunnel - this works! It runs forever, until the shell is quit.
ssh -nNT -L 50000:localhost:3306 jm@sampledomain.com
```

Then, in another shell window, I do my work:

```
# Do some MySQL stuff over local port 50000 (which goes to remote port 3306)
```

Finally, when I am done, I close the first shell window to kill the tunnel.

I'd like to do this all in one script like:

```
# Create tunnel
# Do work
# Kill tunnel
```

How do I keep track of the tunnel process, so I know which one to kill?

Comment: I wrote a script that would help to do ssh tunneling, you can check it out at: https://github.com/gdbtek/ssh-tunneling.git

Answer (score 383, accepted):

You can do this cleanly with an ssh 'control socket'. To talk to an already-running SSH process and get it's pid, kill it etc.  Use the 'control socket' (-M for master and -S for socket) as follows:

```
$ ssh -M -S my-ctrl-socket -fNT -L 50000:localhost:3306 jm@sampledomain.com
$ ssh -S my-ctrl-socket -O check jm@sampledomain.com
Master running (pid=3517) 
$ ssh -S my-ctrl-socket -O exit jm@sampledomain.com
Exit request sent.
```

Note that my-ctrl-socket will be an actual file that is created.

I got this info from [a very RTFM reply on the OpenSSH mailing list](https://web.archive.org/web/20111129014817/http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/openssh/dev/48040#48040).

Comment: This is the best answer I have seen on the topic so far. Thank you a lot, it should be the accepted one. I use this to connect to my Vagrant VM and run a FlywayDB update script.

Comment: Apparently control sockets do not work everywhere. For example, I get `Operation not permitted` on drone.io continuous integration environment: `muxserver_listen: link mux listener ssh-ctrl-socket.wsASkszgSBlK7kqD => ssh-ctrl-socket: Operation not permitted`

Comment: So what happens to the `my-ctrl-socket` file after this is run? When I do `ls -la` in the current folder I can't see the file anymore.

Comment: If you use it in a script you need to wait for the control socket for a few seconds to become available. My solution:
`while [ ! -e $ctrl_socket ]; do sleep 0.1; done`

Comment: when I do this I'm getting `open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed` and I don't think it's opening the tunnel

Comment: @AndyRay this sounds like a misconfiguration on the server side. Does this answer help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/ssh-tunneling-error-channel-1-open-failed-administratively-prohibited-open

Comment: Brilliant stuff, way more elegant then everything else I found online. Thanks

Answer (score 23):

You can tell SSH to background itself with the -f option but you won't get the PID with $!.
Also instead of having your script sleep an arbitrary amount of time before you use the tunnel, you can use -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes with -f and SSH will wait for all remote port forwards to be successfully established before placing itself in the background. You can grep the output of ps to get the PID. For example you can use

```
...
ssh -Cfo ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -N -L 9999:localhost:5900 $REMOTE_HOST
PID=$(pgrep -f 'N -L 9999:')
[ "$PID" ] || exit 1
...
```

and be pretty sure you're getting the desired PID

Comment: You may not realise it, but this is sort of genius. I was searching for a way to track the SSH tunnel PIDs and almost ended up using the systemd service scripts. Not anymore: I can grep the SSH process I need using the tunnel name. This idea has somehow completely skipped me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 19):

- You can tell `ssh` to go into background with `&` and not create a shell on the other side (just open the tunnel) with a command line flag (I see you already did this with `-N`).
- Save the PID with `PID=$!`
- Do your stuff
- `kill $PID`

EDIT: Fixed $? to $! and added the &

Comment: If my script dies somewhere before it gets to the KILL, I have to be careful to handle that.

Comment: @jm: `trap 'kill $PID' 1 2 15` will cover many cases of script failure.

Comment: For this to work reliably, i had to "sleep" a little AFTER creating the tunnel, but before using it.

Comment: @NormanRamsey I think you mean `trap "kill $PID"`, because bash will only interpolate variables inside double quoted strings

Comment: @JuanCaicedo The distinction would only be important if the `PID` variable were redefined later on. The variable is either expanded when the `trap` built-in is called (the OP's approach) or when a signal has been caught (your approach); both approaches produce the same result here.

Comment: sleep is NOT reliable ;)

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to launch a new shell for separate tasks and I often use the following command combination:

```
  $ sudo bash; exit
```

or sometimes:

```
  $ : > sensitive-temporary-data.txt; bash; rm -f sensitive-temporary-data.txt; exit
```

These commands create a nested shell where I can do all my work; when I'm finished I hit CTRL-D and the parent shell cleans up and exits as well. You could easily throw `bash;` into your ssh tunnel script just before the `kill` part so that when you log out of the nested shell your tunnel will be closed:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -nNT ... &
PID=$!
bash
kill $PID
```

Comment: Very interesting. This may handle the "trap" problem better. Will have to try it.

Answer (score 2):

You could launch the `ssh` with a `&` a the end, to put it in the background and grab its id when doing. Then you just have to do a `kill` of that id when you're done.

Comment: Be aware if using the ampersand ("&"). It is an ugly approach since you will have to determine the actual connection established for yourself. It can cause to have further code being executed which is not waiting for the actual connection to be fully established. Furthermore the connection won't be killed automatically if the script breaks.

Answer (score 0):

A simple bash script to solve your problem.

```
# Download then put in $PATH
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ijortengab/bash/master/commands/command-keep-alive.sh
mv command-keep-alive.sh -t /usr/local/bin

# open tunnel, put script in background
command-keep-alive.sh "ssh -fN -o ServerAliveInterval=10 -o ServerAliveCountMax=2 -L 33306:localhost:3306 myserver" /tmp/my.pid &
# do something
mysql --port 33306
# close tunnel
kill $(cat /tmp/my.pid)
```

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/aronpc/remina-ssh-tunnel

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

scriptname="$(basename $0)"
actionname="$1"
tunnelname=$(echo "$2" | iconv -t ascii//TRANSLIT | sed -E 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+/-/g' | sed -E 's/^-+|-+$//g' | tr A-Z a-z)
remotedata="$3"
tunnelssh="$4"

if [ $# -lt 4 ] 
 then
    echo "Usage: $scriptname start | stop LOCAL_PORT:RDP_IP:RDP_PORT SSH_NODE_IP"
    exit
fi

case "$actionname" in

start)

  echo "Starting tunnel to $tunnelssh"
  ssh -M -S ~/.ssh/sockets/$tunnelname.control -fnNT -L $remotedata $tunnelssh
  ssh -S ~/.ssh/sockets/$tunnelname.control -O check $tunnelssh
  ;;

stop)
  echo "Stopping tunnel to $tunnelssh"
  ssh -S ~/.ssh/sockets/$tunnelname.control -O exit $tunnelssh 
 ;;

*)
  echo "Did not understand your argument, please use start|stop"
  ;;

esac
```

### usage example

Edit or create new remmina server connection

**schema**

`~/.ssh/rdp-tunnel.sh ACTION TUNNELNAME LOCAL_PORT:REMOTE_SERVER:REMOTE_PORT TUNNEL_PROXY`

| name | description |
| --- | --- |
| **ACTION** | start|stop |
| **TUNNELNAME** | "string identify socket" slugify to create socket file into ~/.ssh/sockets/string-identify-socket.control |
| **LOCAL_PORT** | the door that will be exposed locally if we use the same port for two connections it will crash |
| **REMOTE_SERVER** | the ip of the server that you would access if you had it on the proxy server that will be used |
| **REMOTE_PORT** | the service port that runs on the server |
| **TUNNEL_PROXY** | the connection you are going to use as a proxy, it needs to be in your ~/.ssh/config preferably using the access keys |

I use the combination **(% g-% p)** of the remmina group name and connection name to be my TUNNELNAME (this needs to be unique, it will see the socket name)

**pre-command**

`~/.ssh/rdp-tunnel.sh start "%g-%p" 63394:192.168.8.176:3389 tunnel-name-1`

**post-command**

`~/.ssh/rdp-tunnel.sh stop "%g-%p" 63394:192.168.8.176:3389 tunnel-name-1`

[image]

**you can and should use this script to access anything, I use it constantly to access systems and services that do not have a public ip going through 1,2,3,4,5 or more ssh proxies**

see more into :

1. [ssh config](https://linuxize.com/post/using-the-ssh-config-file/)
2. [ssh mach](https://mike.place/2017/ssh-match/)
3. [ssh jump hosts](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts)
4. [sshuttle python ssh](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle)

Refs:

1. https://remmina.org/remmina-rdp-ssh-tunnel/
2. https://kgibran.wordpress.com/2019/03/13/remmina-rdp-ssh-tunnel-with-pre-and-post-scripts/
3. [Bash script to set up a temporary SSH tunnel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241063/bash-script-to-setup-a-temporary-ssh-tunnel/15198031#15198031)
4. https://gist.github.com/oneohthree/f528c7ae1e701ad990e6

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28511851)

Comment: thanks, I managed to put readme.md, I didn't know I had