# docker-compose --context no output

Tags: docker, docker-compose

`docker-compose --context remote (up|dows|ps|...)` doesn't do anything.
although `docker --context remote ps` works, connects to the remote and lists the containters. also, running it locally is ok (just `docker-compose up`)

`docker --version` on local machine: `Docker version 20.10.2, build 2291f610ae`

`docker --version` on remote machine: `Docker version 20.10.2, build 2291f61`

`docker-compose version` on local machine:

```
docker-compose version 1.28.0, build unknown
docker-py version: 4.4.1
CPython version: 3.9.1
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1i  8 Dec 2020
```

I don't know what other thing to provide.

EDIT: `docker-compose -H "ssh://user@host" up` does exactly that what the `--context` does, nothing.

`docker-compose --verbose --context remote up` prints out just this: `compose.config.config.find: Using configuration files: ./docker-compose.yml`

Comment: The --context option doesn't appear in the docs... what about [using -H to pass the remote host](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/)? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53524793/1941519) covers setting the DOCKER_HOST environment variable as an alternative

Comment: It's strange that --context isn't in the docs. because it is in `docker-compose --help`. creating a ssh tunnel and then running `docker-compose -H "tcp://localhost:2377" up` prints out a error: `docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))`

Comment: Have you tried connecting to SSH directly in docker-compose? `docker-compose -H "ssh://user@host" up`

Comment: Now that I've read up on contexts, you could try adding the `--verbose` flag to your context call and if anything useful comes out, add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

for me, COMPOSE_PARAMIKO_SSH=1 fixed it. Not 100% sure why- something something reusing ssh connections