# docker-compose fails to run on remote host from local

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Via my local I would like to run docker-compose on my remote machine. I have found two ways that should accomplish this but am running into errors.

Fist I am running the following versions:

```
me:api$ docker-compose  -v
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build unknown
me:api$ docker -v
Docker version 20.10.7, build 20.10.7-0ubuntu5~20.04.2
```

First way and the way I would prefer for this to work is to the the `--context` flag. Based on this [blog post](https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-deploy-on-remote-docker-hosts-with-docker-compose/) should be possible.

I created the context like so:

```
docker context create prod --docker "host=ssh://user@host.com"
```

I can then run the following and get an output of running containers

```
docker --context prod ps
```

However running with `docker-compose` the command fails

```
docker-compose --context prod -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d
ERROR: Context 'prod' not found
```

The other option was to use the `-H` flag based on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35517112/2612651) to set the host that I want to execute the commands on. Yes I can SSH into my machine with the user I am using.

```
docker-compose -H ssh://user@host -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d
/bin/sh: 1: ssh: Permission denied
```

Comment: Please review this unless not done already https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-deploy-on-remote-docker-hosts-with-docker-compose/

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee that is referenced in the question.

Comment: Looks like at least the latest `docker compose` is working with DOCKER_HOST like `DOCKER_HOST="ssh://user@host" docker compose logs` does not give the permission denied.

Answer (score 0):

Well it does not look great. I have not been able to get any of the methods to work with `docker-compose` however there is a new (at the time of writing this) `docker compose` replacement from docker. The instructions are [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/cli-command/#installing-compose-v2). I was hoping that the `--context` flag would work but it is not found with the new version which leads me to believe that it did not work before. The `-H` flag lead to the same Permission Denied error as before.

The only way I was able to get this to work was by setting the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable.